# Windows 7 corrupted folder can't delete

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I was installing the game Assassin's Creed after it was on Uplay but somewhere along the line, I accidentally pulled the plug out from my computer and it went off.

When I turned it on and tried to play the game, it would give me an error that it cannot find the Uplay dll. I tried to open the folder of Uplay and it shows this.

[image: screenshot here]

So I tried deleting it, even on my admin account but it won't.

[image: Screenshot here]

I uninstalled my game hoping it would help but it has not.

How do I delete this folder? If possible, is there any software to do it? I am really not keen to use any in-depth methods that may or may not damage my PC if I make a mistake.

Comment: When you get "the file or directory is corrupt" then normally it's a good idea to make a backup if you don't have an up-to-date one (do NOT overwrite your older backup) and then run `chkdsk` (also available in Windows Explorer as (D:) drive -> Properties -> Tools -> Check for Errors)

Answer (score 0):

Deleted through Safemode with Networking.

Other methods wouldn't work and i was skeptical on the suggested 3rd party programs to use.

I guess it's somewhat contradictory to my statement in the post.

Still solved my problem.

Comment: You should still run `chkdsk` if you haven’t done so already.